# Is it possible to configure Sahi to support OnMouseEnter events?

Tags: sahi

I am trying to test a site with a drop down menu which is expanded by on onmouseenter event. I know this event is IE only, but I am unable to get the event to record/playback using Sahi in IE8 or IE9.

In the Sahi config there is a file htdocs\spr\concat.js which appears to contain event handling. I have tried to modify this file to add support for the extra event by duplicating the _mouserOver event and renaming it to _mouseEnter. I have also added _mouseEnter to the scheduler_functions.txt config file.

Unfortunately this had no effect.

Does Sahi support configuring extra events? If so, what is the process for adding extra events?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Sahi supports configuring extra events. The process you followed is correct but you need to restart Sahi and clear browser cache for this to take effect.

Can you provide more details about the changes you made in the concat.js file.